# Confusion about writing files from lambda to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So, I have a lambda function which does some work to create a list of POJOs. I want to write that list of POJOs to a Snappy parquet file, and upload that file to an S3 bucket.

The ParquetWriter libs im looking at require a Path. If I were running this code on my local machine, then I would simply write the file out to some local directory and then make a separate call to upload this to s3. However, because this code is running in a lambda, im not sure where I'm supposed to write the parquet file "to", like I'm not sure if there's even a temp file system I can access from a lambda. So, I'm not sure how to leverage normal ParquetWriter libraries which require a file system Path.

Where am I supposed to first write the file I want to upload to s3, when the file writing code is happening in a lambda?

Comment: Either write the file to `/tmp`, and upload it from there, or save to memory and use `put_object()`  to upload from memory to S3.

Comment: @AnonCoward can you explain where I would write the file if I want to "save to memory"? Yeah, I want to use put_object to upload to my bucket. I'm just not sure where to actually "save" the file first

Comment: Saving to memory does not involve a filename.  Use something like `io.BytesIO` to create a file-like object that a process can write to, then upload the results of `getvalue()` after you've serialized the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AnonCoward is right. In a Lambda function, you can write data to the `/tmp` directory. This directory is writable, but not persistent. This means that data stored in `/tmp` can be lost after a Lambda function invocation ends or when the Lambda function is re-used.

I think an example of what @AnonCoward is talking about is something like this:

```
import boto3
import io
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Data
    data = [{"id": 1, "name": "John"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Jane"}]
    
    # Serialize
    table = pq.Table.from_pandas(data)
    output_stream = io.BytesIO()
    pq.write_table(table, output_stream)
    parquet_data = output_stream.getvalue()
    
    # Upload to S3
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    s3.put_object(Bucket="my-bucket", Key="data.parquet", Body=parquet_data)
    
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": "Parquet file uploaded to S3"
    }
```